# TcpClient Recommended Sending Intervals?

Tags: c#, network-programming

The MSDN help file says that you should always send a message out to a client on a TcpClient before checking it's Connected state. Which I've done and it works very well.

The problem is how costly is this in the long run of multiple clients(hundreds, thousands)? Currently I have this sample code I am testing with:

```
Array.Clear( myBufferW , 0 , NetworkVars.TcpBufferWriteSize );
ByteBuffer.Buffer_SetOffset( 0 );
ByteBuffer.Buffer_Writeu8( ref myBufferW , ( byte ) 253 );
TcpPackets.TcpPacketSend( myStream , myBufferW , ByteBuffer.Buffer_GetOffset() );
if ( myClient.Connected == false ) {
    myThreading = false;
}
```

Would it be costly to *always* send this message in every TcpClient? If I only did this check every so often though, would it be costly for hundreds or thousands of TcpClients to prompt this message all simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot find out whether a TCP connection is still alive without sending data and either receiving a reply or waiting for the timeout of the TCP stack. So your code does not reliably detect connection problems right now.

Probably the best way to fix this is have the remote party reply with an acknowledgement.

> Would it be costly to always send this message in every TcpClient?

The cost of doing this is to send and receive a small packet. It also costs a little CPU time. What answer do you expect here? What's costly depends on how much resources the server has and what else is going on. I cannot tell you whether this is *too* costly for your case.

Measure the performance cost. Does not seem particularly hard to do here.

Comment: Well, from what I know, you don't have to receive a reply to update the Connected property, so I thought that would work. Honestly I don't think it's too much to send about 2 bytes. The answer I expect is a generalized estimate. I'll test the performance cost and see what happens.

Comment: Yeah it's probably ok. If the packet is 100 bytes and you have 100k connected clients then one cycle costs 10MB which is ~1sec on 100Mbps.

Comment: You certainly have to receive a reply because just sending a packet does not mean that it will ever be received. TCP does not await acknowledgement after each packet. That would destroy performance.

Comment: Ah good point. I'll work through and have it update after packet reception. The checking packet is very tiny, 2 bytes + 36(?) byte TCP overhead; so I shouldn't have any problems.